# Rails `edit_joke_path` Links to the Show View, Not the Edit View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what should be a fairly simple `link_to` situation:

```
<% @jokes.each do |joke| %>
  ...
  <%= link_to edit_joke_path(joke) do %>
    <span style="color: blue" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span><span style="color: blue">Edit Joke</span>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

However, when I click this link it takes me to the `jokes#show` page not the `jokes#edit` page.  Here are my routes:

```
               jokes GET    /jokes(.:format)               jokes#index
                     POST   /jokes(.:format)               jokes#create
            new_joke GET    /jokes/new(.:format)           jokes#new
           edit_joke GET    /jokes/:id/edit(.:format)      jokes#edit
                joke GET    /jokes/:id(.:format)           jokes#show
                     PATCH  /jokes/:id(.:format)           jokes#update
                     PUT    /jokes/:id(.:format)           jokes#update
                     DELETE /jokes/:id(.:format)           jokes#destroy
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  This seems really simple, but it's not working the way it should.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Here's the `edit` action from my `jokes_controller`:

```
 def edit
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
    @joke.user = current_user
    @joke.save
    redirect_to joke_path
  end
```

Comment: Your code is currect, provide the `edit` action code from `jokes_controller.rb`

Comment: @hgsongra, nope.  Even after a restart it still goes to the `show` page.

Comment: I update my comment, please see and provide details

Comment: @hgsongra, it's added to the OP.

Comment: Here is the issue `redirect_to joke_path` this code redirect your page to `jokes#show` after updating object

Comment: `# redirect_to joke_path` comment this line, it will resoved your issue

Comment: @hgsongra, yes!  This was it!  Thank you!

Comment: Why are you modifying the `@joke` on the edit action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per below code in `jokes_controller.rb`

```
 def edit
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
    @joke.user = current_user
    @joke.save
    redirect_to joke_path
  end
```

`redirect_to joke_path` cause the issue.

So, remove or comment below line in your `edit`  action it will resolve your issue.

```
redirect_to joke_path
```

Comment: It would be nice explain why that corrects his problem

Comment: I meant to say he doesn't need to redirect because rails will match the action name with the view and render the `edit` view automatically. And that's why removing the line you mentioned solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
edit_joke_path(joke)
```

goes to jokes#edit but at the end of the edit fuction you have added **redirect_to**. Remove redirect_to from the edit function.

> redirect_to: Redirects the browser to the target specified

Answer (score 0):

Remove `redirect_to joke_path` from your action. That's taking you to the show page.